# Drag scrolling jagged in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I made a click and drag scrolling Image Viewer [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rwsq4/5/).

It works like a charm in FF and Chrome, but IE is behaving weird. The **diagonal movement** is jagged, as if the scrolling is slow and every movement is seperately visible.

I'm scrolling the DIV like this (viewPort is a jQuery object).

```
viewPort[0].scrollTop = newy;
viewPort[0].scrollLeft = newx;
```

Is anybody able to create a smooth movement in IE9 and IE10?

**Edit:**
I'm using IE10 on Windows 7. I've seen it working on IE10 on Windows 8.

Comment: Might be your version of IE. Once loaded it drags fine in my IE in both IE10 and IE9 mode. I would say, IE is very picky and different on every machine. IE on my computer takes over 2 minutes to load google homepage on first start, and is extremely slow navigating URLs, even though ive not used it for anything but testing websites (so its not a plugin issue). Might be worth testing it in IE on another machine so you can check its not just you. Also worth noting, the 2.x versions of jquery do not fully support <IE9 so if your running XP IE8 or less, you may have issues anyway

Comment: Hmm... on another machine it works. At this point it is just me..

Comment: What is your OS? I've seen more issues on unique machine's and most of the time the grapical card is the issue.

Comment: Windows 7. I've seen it working on IE10 on Windows 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a good practice, when dealing with `mousemove/touchmove`, to apply UI changes in a `requestAnimationFrame` callback. Consider this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwsq4/8/)

I am not sure if this helps, but it is definitely some better approach.

---

There is event better solution with `transforms`. You apply for an image `position:absolute` styles and for the container `overflow:hidden` and `position:relative`. After that, you change not the `scrollLeft/scrollTop` of the container, but `translate(Xpx,Ypx)` for the image itself.